# Can I pass in multiple typed arrays into Asm.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, asm.js

Suppose I have a bunch of Int32Arrays and Float32Arrays in my javascript file. I wish to perform a bunch of computations on them using Asm.js.

However Asm.js only seems to have a singleton array for it's entire memory heap.

Is there a way of passing in multiple Int32Arrays and Float32Arrays to be available for processing in Asm.js, without copying their contents into a singleton array first? (How could a singleton array contain both value types?)

Comment: what is meant by "pass"ing "into ASM.js"? i thought asm was not for humans to write code for...

Comment: Yes, I plan to have asm.js code generated by my program. I'm a bit new to it though. It must be possible to pass in data to an asm.js script from the javascript?

Comment: "*How could a singleton array contain both value types?*" - it's a `Buffer` of raw bytes actually.

Comment: @BrendanHill "I plan to have asm.js code generated by my program". Can you expand a bit on this? What are the specifics of the program generating the asm.js?